Transposed editable DataGridView from list and datatable with vb.net
I'm Trying make Transposed editable DataGridView from list and datatable with vb.net.
so in Datagridview1 Transposed editable (From list) with result in Datagridview1 non Transposed and non  editable and in Datagridview2 Transposed editable (From datatable) with result in Datagridview4 non Transposed and non  editable.
I found the answer from @RezaAghaei (below link) in the C# programming language but I tried the code with the programming language VB.NET there was an error in method Default Public Property Item(ByVal i As Integer) As Object
Link
Please Guide me
Thanks
Result below code Answer from the link above with conversion to vb.net
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Linq
Public Class RotatedListDataSource(Of T)
    Inherits List(Of RotatedItem)

    Public ReadOnly Property List As List(Of T)
    Public Sub New(ByVal list As List(Of T))
        Me.List = list
        Me.AddRange(GetType(T).GetProperties().Select(Function(p) New RotatedItem(p.Name, list.Cast(Of Object)().ToArray(), p.PropertyType)))
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class RotatedItem
    Inherits CustomTypeDescriptor

    Public ReadOnly Property PropertyName As String
    Private data() As Object
    Public ReadOnly Property Type As Type
    Public Sub New(ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal data() As Object, ByVal type As Type)
        Me.PropertyName = propertyName
        Me.data = data
        Me.Type = type
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function GetProperties() As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Return Me.GetProperties(New Attribute() {})
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function GetProperties(ByVal attributes() As Attribute) As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Dim properties = New List(Of PropertyDescriptor)()
        properties.Add(New PropertyNameProperty(New Attribute() {New BrowsableAttribute(False)}))
        For i As Integer = 0 To data.Length - 1
            properties.Add(New IndexProperty(i, GetType(Object), New Attribute() {}))
        Next i
        Return New PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.ToArray())
    End Function
    Default Public Property Item(ByVal i As Integer) As Object
        Get
'Error below line Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'GetValue' accepts this number of arguments.
            Return data(i).GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(data(i))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
'Error below line Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'SetValue' accepts this number of arguments.
            data(i).GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).SetValue(data(i), Convert.ChangeType(value, Type))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Public Class IndexProperty
    Inherits PropertyDescriptor

    Private index As Integer
    Private type As Type
    Public Sub New(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal type As Type, ByVal attributes() As Attribute)
        MyBase.New(index.ToString(), attributes)
        Me.index = index
        Me.type = type
    End Sub
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(RotatedItem)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PropertyType As Type
        Get
            Return type
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides Function CanResetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function GetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Object
        Return DirectCast(component, RotatedItem)(index)
    End Function
    Public Overrides Sub ResetValue(ByVal component As Object)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub SetValue(ByVal component As Object, ByVal value As Object)
        DirectCast(component, RotatedItem)(index) = value
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
Public Class PropertyNameProperty
    Inherits PropertyDescriptor

    Public Sub New(ByVal attributes() As Attribute)
        MyBase.New(NameOf(RotatedItem.PropertyName), attributes)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(RotatedItem)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PropertyType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(String)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides Function CanResetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function GetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Object
        Return DirectCast(component, RotatedItem).PropertyName
    End Function
    Public Overrides Sub ResetValue(ByVal component As Object)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub SetValue(ByVal component As Object, ByVal value As Object)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class


Public Class Form1
    Private Sub LISTEMP()
        Dim Product As New List(Of Product)() From {
    New Product() With {
        .Codeproduct = "SHIRTA",
        .Productname = "SHIRT WHITE",
        .Size = "S",
        .Qty = 1
    },
      New Product() With {
        .Codeproduct = "SHIRTB",
        .Productname = "SHIRT BLACK",
        .Size = "M",
        .Qty = 1
    },
    New Product() With {
        .Codeproduct = "SHIRTC",
        .Productname = "SHIRT YELLOW",
        .Size = "L",
        .Qty = 1
    },
    New Product() With {
        .Codeproduct = "SHIRTD",
        .Productname = "SHIRT GREEN",
        .Size = "XL",
        .Qty = 1
    },
   New Product() With {
        .Codeproduct = "SHIRTE",
        .Productname = "SHIRT YELLOW",
        .Size = "2L",
        .Qty = 1
    }
}
     DataGridView1.DataSource = Product.ToList()
    End Sub
    Private Sub datatableEMP()
        Dim Product As New DataTable()
        Product.Columns.Add("Codeproduct", GetType(String))
        Product.Columns.Add("Productname", GetType(String))
        Product.Columns.Add("Size", GetType(String))
         Product.Columns.Add("Qty", GetType(Integer))
        Product.Rows.Add("SHIRTA", "SHIRT WHITE", "S", 1)
        Product.Rows.Add("SHIRTB", "SHIRT BLACK", "M", 1)
        Product.Rows.Add("SHIRTC", "SHIRT YELLOW", "L", 1)
        Product.Rows.Add("SHIRTD", "SHIRT GREEN", "XL", 1)
        Product.Rows.Add("SHIRTE", "SHIRT YELLOW", "2L", 1)


        DataGridView2.DataSource = Product
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LISTEMP()
        datatableEMP()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Product
    Public Property Codeproduct As String
    Public Property Productname As String
    Public Property Size As String
    Public Property Qty As Integer
End Class

result from my code

Desired result
Datagridview1 Transposed editable (From list)



Codeproduct
Productname
S
M
L
XL
2L




SHIRTA
SHIRT WHITE
1






SHIRTB
SHIRT BLACK

1





SHIRTC
SHIRT YELLOW


1




SHIRTD
SHIRT GREEN



1



SHIRTE
SHIRT YELLOW




1



Datagridview2 Transposed editable (From Datatable)



Codeproduct
Productname
S
M
L
XL
2L




SHIRTA
SHIRT WHITE
1






SHIRTB
SHIRT BLACK

1





SHIRTC
SHIRT YELLOW


1




SHIRTD
SHIRT GREEN



1



SHIRTE
SHIRT YELLOW




1



Datagridview3 result Non Transposed and non editable from datagridview1 (From list)



Codeproduct
Productname
Size
Qty




SHIRTA
SHIRT WHITE
S
1


SHIRTB
SHIRT BLACK
M
1


SHIRTC
SHIRT YELLOW
L
1


SHIRTD
SHIRT GREEN
XL
1


SHIRTE
SHIRT YELLOW
2L
1



Datagridview4 result Non Transposed and non editable from datagridview2 (From Datatable)



Codeproduct
Productname
Size
Qty




SHIRTA
SHIRT WHITE
S
1


SHIRTB
SHIRT BLACK
M
1


SHIRTC
SHIRT YELLOW
L
1


SHIRTD
SHIRT GREEN
XL
1


SHIRTE
SHIRT YELLOW
2L
1




The code that I got from code converters didn't work and I needed to change it a little. I posted the VB version of the code.

Here is a VB version of my original post. The code that I got from code converters didn't work and I needed to change it a little. This VB version works as expected.
Main classes
These are the classes which implement the rotated data source from original list, with help of a custom type descriptor:
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Linq
Public Class RotatedListDataSource(Of T)
    Inherits List(Of RotatedItem)
    Public ReadOnly Property List As List(Of T)
    Public Sub New(ByVal list As List(Of T))
        list = list
        Me.AddRange(GetType(T).GetProperties() _
          .Select(Function(p)
                      Return New RotatedItem(p.Name, list.Cast(Of Object)().ToArray(), p.PropertyType)
                  End Function))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class RotatedItem
    Inherits CustomTypeDescriptor
    Public ReadOnly Property PropertyName As String
    Private data As Object()
    Public ReadOnly Property Type As Type
    Public Sub New(ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal data As Object(), ByVal type As Type)
        Me.PropertyName = propertyName
        Me.data = data
        Me.Type = type
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function GetProperties() As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Return Me.GetProperties(New Attribute() {})
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function GetProperties(ByVal attributes As Attribute()) As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Dim properties = New List(Of PropertyDescriptor)()
        properties.Add(New PropertyNameProperty(New Attribute() {New BrowsableAttribute(False)}))

        For i As Integer = 0 To data.Length - 1
            properties.Add(New IndexProperty(i, GetType(Object), New Attribute() {}))
        Next

        Return New PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.ToArray())
    End Function
    Default Public Property Item(ByVal i As Integer) As Object
        Get
            Return data(i).GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(data(i))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            data(i).GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).SetValue(data(i), Convert.ChangeType(value, Type))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class IndexProperty
    Inherits PropertyDescriptor
    Private index As Integer
    Private type As Type
    Public Sub New(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal type As Type, ByVal attributes As Attribute())
        MyBase.New(index.ToString(), attributes)
        Me.index = index
        Me.type = type
    End Sub
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(RotatedItem)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PropertyType As Type
        Get
            Return type
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides Function CanResetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function GetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Object
        Return (CType(component, RotatedItem))(index)
    End Function
    Public Overrides Sub ResetValue(ByVal component As Object)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub SetValue(ByVal component As Object, ByVal value As Object)
        CType(component, RotatedItem)(index) = value
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class

Public Class PropertyNameProperty
    Inherits PropertyDescriptor
    Public Sub New(ByVal attributes As Attribute())
        MyBase.New(NameOf(RotatedItem.PropertyName), attributes)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(RotatedItem)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PropertyType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(String)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides Function CanResetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function GetValue(ByVal component As Object) 
        Return (CType(component, RotatedItem)).PropertyName
    End Function
    Public Overrides Sub ResetValue(ByVal component As Object)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub SetValue(ByVal component As Object, ByVal value As Object)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class

Employee class
This is the Employee class which is used in the example usage of the rotated data source
Public Class Employee
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property City As String
End Class

Example
The following example shows how you can show a rotated list (transposed list) in a DataGridView:
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Data
        Dim list As New List(Of Employee) From
        {
            New Employee With {.Id = 1, .Name = "John", .City = "New York"},
            New Employee With {.Id = 2, .Name = "Steve", .City = "London"},
            New Employee With {.Id = 3, .Name = "Lucas", .City = "Paris"}
        }

        'Set Data Source of the DataGridView
        DGV.DataSource = New RotatedListDataSource(Of Employee)(list)

        'Hide Column Headers
        DGV.ColumnHeadersVisible = False

        'Set Row Headers Autosize
        DGV.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders

        'Show PropertyName on RowHeader
        AddHandler DGV.RowPrePaint,
            Sub(o, a)
                Dim value = CType(DGV.Rows(a.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, RotatedItem).PropertyName
                If a.RowIndex > -1 And $"{DGV.Rows(a.RowIndex).HeaderCell.Value}" <> value Then
                    DGV.Rows(a.RowIndex).HeaderCell.Value = value
                End If
            End Sub
    End Sub
End Class


Thank you for your answer and sorry I was late replying to you. for this line code Public Overrides Function GetValue(ByVal component As Object) there is an error so i have to make it look like this  Public Overrides Function GetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Object. Errors like this Error BC30210 Option Strict On requires all Function, Property, and Operator declarations to have an As clause

is it possible to be the desired result as posted according to my sample data?, please guide me

Can you add your answer with a datatable example?
